# Why does the React dialog require componentWillReceiveProps and popup again when Stepper changes?

Tags: reactjs, material-design

I have a react app which uses Material UI. I want to have a dialog which can be opened multiple times. And, a dialog which is used on one step of a "stepper".

The below code does allow me to open the dialog multiple times, but the way I got this working was to add `componentWillReceiveProps` and this solution seems odd. Without the `componentWillReceiveProps` the dialog opens the first time, but not on any successive clicks. Is there a better way to allow it to reset the props passed in? I assume my issue is that the props are set the first time the component is created, and then the app does not recreate the component and the props use the old value that is set on the close event?

In addition, there is strange behavior when I move between steps. If I click on step 2, the dialog pops up. How do I refactor to avoid this behavior?

These patterns are more or less copied from the examples here: https://material-ui.com/

```
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Stepper from '@material-ui/core/Stepper';
import Step from '@material-ui/core/Step';
import StepLabel from '@material-ui/core/StepLabel';
import StepContent from '@material-ui/core/StepContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';

class FullScreenDialog extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.state.isOpen = props.isOpen;
    }

    handleClickOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: true });
    };

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState( { isOpen: nextProps.isOpen } );
    }

    handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: false });
    };

    render() {
    return (
        <Dialog fullScreen open={this.state.isOpen} onClose={this.handleClose}>
        <AppBar >
        <Toolbar>
        <IconButton color="inherit" onClick={this.handleClose} aria-label="Close">
        <CloseIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" >
        A dialog
        </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <div>
        { /* Without both of these I don't see the content */ }
        <h1>The body of the dialog.</h1>
        <h1>The body of the dialog.</h1>
        </div>
        </Dialog>
    );
    }
}

class VerticalLinearStepper extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { noteDialogIsOpen: false, activeStep: 0 };
    }

    getSteps() {
    return ['First step', 'Second step'];
    }

    getStepContent(step, doc, query) {
    switch (step) {
    case 0:
        return (
        <Typography>
            { this.state.noteDialogIsOpen &&
            <FullScreenDialog isOpen={this.state.noteDialogIsOpen} query={query} doc={doc}/>
        }
        <Button onClick={this.openNoteDialog}>Open dialog.</Button>
        </Typography>
        )
    case 1:
        return "Something or other";
    default:
        return "Unsure";
    }
    }

    openNoteDialog = () => {
    this.setState( { noteDialogIsOpen: true } );
    }

    onClose() {
    this.setState( { noteDialogIsOpen: false } );
    }

    handleNext = () => {
    this.setState({
        activeStep: this.state.activeStep + 1,
    });
    };

    handleBack = () => {
    this.setState({
        activeStep: this.state.activeStep - 1,
    });
    };

    handleReset = () => {
    this.setState({
        activeStep: 0,
    });
    };

    render() {
    const { query, doc } = this.props;
    const steps = this.getSteps();
    const { activeStep } = this.state;

    return (
            <div>
        <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} orientation="vertical">
        {steps.map((label, index) => {
        return (
            <Step key={label}>
            <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
            <StepContent>
            {this.getStepContent(index,doc,query)}
            <Button disabled={activeStep === 0} onClick={this.handleBack}>Back</Button>
            <Button onClick={this.handleNext}>
            {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
            </Button>
            </StepContent>
            </Step>
        );
        })}
        </Stepper>
        {activeStep === steps.length && (
        <Paper square elevation={0} >
        <Typography>All steps completed.</Typography>
        <Button onClick={this.handleReset}>
        Reset
        </Button>
        </Paper>
        )}
        </div>
    );
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
<VerticalLinearStepper query="asdasdasd" doc="asdadasdsa"/>
</div>,
  document.getElementById('react-container')
```

This is probably two distinct questions but they are so intertwined I don't see how separating them makes it possible to ask either in isolation...

If it matters, the package.json is here:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.0.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^1.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-navigation": "^2.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
   "start": "PORT=3006 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

This was created using `create-react-app` and modified to include material design

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make the Dialog stateless and handle if it's opened by props only? The reason of this behavior is that the constructor of the dialog is called once only, and since you're making a copy of the state change of the parent component inside the Dialog component, you need to use componentWillReceiveProps or componentDidUpdate to reflect the changes of the parent inside the child. And in the current version of React the suggested function to handle these changes would be componentDidUpdate.

Comment: If you want to give me an example of making it stateless, I would happily accept it as the answer. I'm new to react and unsure how to refactor to do that.

Comment: Ok i'm making it but there is a problem, a Dialog in material should be openned and closed only, if you want a Step to have a Dialog inside you shouldn't use the Dialog component itself inside of it, but a new div with the content that you need, i'm making some changes in your code and will post the answer in a few minutes

Comment: For example, if the open prop is not eventually set to false in the state, then I don't see how else to close the dialog. That's what you mean by making it stateless right, setting open to a prop rather than a state variable?

Comment: Yes, you need to have it handled in the state only, and sending it in props. Check my answer if it solves your problem. If you have any other question please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i changed both classes, making the Dialog stateless. By doing this you don't need to replicate data, having all concern handled inside the VerticalLineStepper class.

```
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Stepper from '@material-ui/core/Stepper';
import Step from '@material-ui/core/Step';
import StepLabel from '@material-ui/core/StepLabel';
import StepContent from '@material-ui/core/StepContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';

const FullScreenDialog = props => {
    return (
        <Dialog fullScreen open={props.isOpen} onClose={props.handleClose}>
            <AppBar >
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton color="inherit" onClick={props.handleClose} aria-label="Close">
                        <CloseIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" >
                    A dialog
                </Typography>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            <div>
            { /* Without both of these I don't see the content */ }
            <h1>The body of the dialog.</h1>
            <h1>The body of the dialog.</h1>
            </div>
        </Dialog>
    );
};

class VerticalLinearStepper extends Component {
    state = { 
        noteDialogIsOpen: false, 
        activeStep: 0 
    };

    getSteps() {
        return ['First step', 'Second step'];
    }

    getStepContent(step) {
        switch (step) {
            case 0:
                return (<Button onClick={this.openNoteDialog}>Open dialog.</Button>);
            case 1:
                return (<div>Something or other</div>);
            default:
                return  (<div>Unsure</div>);
        }
    }

    openNoteDialog = () => {
        this.setState({ noteDialogIsOpen: true });
    };

    closeDialog = () => {
        this.setState({ noteDialogIsOpen: false });
    };

    handleNext = () => {
        this.setState({
            activeStep: this.state.activeStep + 1,
        });
    };

    handleBack = () => {
        this.setState({
            activeStep: this.state.activeStep - 1,
        });
    };

    handleReset = () => {
        this.setState({
            activeStep: 0,
        });
    };

    render() {
        const steps = this.getSteps();
        const { activeStep } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} orientation="vertical">
                    {steps.map((label, index) => {
                    return (
                        <Step key={label}>
                            <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
                            <StepContent>
                                {this.getStepContent(index)}
                                <Button disabled={activeStep === 0} onClick={this.handleBack}>Back</Button>
                                <Button onClick={this.handleNext}>
                                    {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
                                </Button>
                            </StepContent>
                        </Step>
                    );
                    })}
                </Stepper>
                {activeStep === steps.length && (
                <Paper square elevation={0} >
                    <Typography>All steps completed.</Typography>
                    <Button onClick={this.handleReset}>
                        Reset
                    </Button>
                </Paper>
                )}
                <FullScreenDialog 
                    isOpen={this.state.noteDialogIsOpen} 
                    query={this.props.query} 
                    doc={this.props.doc}
                    handleClose={this.closeDialog}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render( <div> <VerticalLinearStepper query="asdasdasd" doc="asdadasdsa"/> </div>, document.getElementById('react-container')
);
```

Comment: Terrific! Works perfectly.